# Java Array random letter combination (not ArrayList)

Tags: arrays, computer-science

Hey guys I want to create a program that output all the possible strings with the letters  ( c, a, t, d, o, g)

like

```
c
c,a
c,a,t
c,a,d
...
.....
......
etc
```

I am wondering if there is anyway to do this without using an arraylist? I looked through other questions and all they have is arrayList not just normal array

can I just do something like:

> String myArray[] = {c, a, t, d,o,g}

and then go from there? I am not sure what to do next though

Thanks

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: arrays are immutable, there seems to be some obvious benefits by using an arrayList.

Comment: @SeekingAlpha: You might want to look over that again.

Comment: well do you want to return just the chars/strings or another array?

Comment: @rendon no, it is just one of my practice problem on my own

Comment: @SeekingAlpha I just want the return all the possible combination, I am not sure if this make sense

Comment: eg {a,b,c}: 1)a 2) b 3) c 4)ab 5) ac 6)bc 7) abc 8) bac 9) bca 10) acb 11) cab 12) cba etc...

Comment: @SeekingAlpha yeah, something like that

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to give complete solutions but is up to you if you want to learn the theory behind this.

```
public void comb(String A[], String str, int pos, int length)
{
    if (length == 0) {
        System.out.println(str);
    } else {
        for (int i = pos; i < A.length; i++)
            comb(A, str + A[i], i + 1, length - 1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myArray[] = {"c", "a", "t", "d","o","g"};
    C c = new C();
    for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++)
        c.comb(myArray, "", 0, i);
}
```

In this [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391367/generating-unique-ids-with-the-max-length-of-3-digits-letters-simbols/21391643#21391643) I explain briefly how a similar generator works.

I also recommend you to learn about [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) and combinatorial algorithms.

**EDIT:** If what you want is to store the combinations in the array the only way I can think of is to initialize with enough space to store all such combinations, for example:

```
private String[] combinations;
private int count;
public void comb(String A[], String str, int pos, int length)
{
    if (length == 0) {
        combinations[count] = str;
        count++;
    } else {
        for (int i = pos; i < A.length; i++)
            comb(A, str + A[i], i + 1, length - 1);
    }
}

public void solve()
{
    // 64 = C(6, 6) + C(6, 5) + C(6, 4) + C(6, 3) + C(6, 2) + C(6, 1) + C(6, 0)
    // where C(n, k) = binomial coefficient function.
    combinations = new String[64];
    count = 0;
    String myArray[] = {"c", "a", "t", "d","o","g"};
    for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++)
        comb(myArray, "", 0, i);

    for (int i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++)
        System.out.println(combinations[i]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C();
    c.solve();
}
```