# Generate all possible combinations for a vector of dimension 9

Tags: combinations, permutation

Let `v =  {x: x in {-1,0,1}}` such that the dimension of`|v| = 9`

Every element `x` in vector `v` can take `3` possible values `-1,0` or `1`

How can I generate all the possible combinations of vector `v` ?

---

`Example:` v = {1,0,-1,0,0,1,1,1,0}, v = {-1,0,-1,1,0,0,1,1,0} etc...

Will i have `3^9` combinations?

thank you.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Thierry I am using C++. I was late to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using python, you can simply do that:

```
import itertools
v = itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat=9)
# v will be a generator
# to have the whole list as tuples
list_v = list(v)

# Verify the number of combination
print len(list(v))
```

And it gives you: 19683, or 3^9

Comment: thank you @Thierry. I am trying to find a similar tool to itertools.product in c++

Comment: What about that: https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

The idea is this:

Your have a position for each element of *v* (9 in your case):

```
- - - - - - - - -
```

Each position can hold three different values (-1 | 0 | 1) and then the total number of combinations is equal to 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 3^9.

To generate such combinations only simulate this process, for example with for loops, e.g. for three positions:

```
values[] = {-1, 0, 1};
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            print values[i], values[j], values[k]
```

In your case you need nine nested loops! An easier implementation will involve recursion but its sometimes more complicated to understand. Here is the idea anyway:

```
values[] = {-1, 0, 1};
void generate(int position)
{
    if (position == 0) {
        println();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        print(values[i], ", ");
        generate(position - 1);
    }
}

// call the function with
generate(9);
```

This [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391367/generating-unique-ids-with-the-max-length-of-3-digits-letters-simbols/21391643#21391643) explains a little more how a recursive generator works.

Comment: thank you @rendn. Well i don't think that it can work in my case this is the code that I implemented in c++ it's the same you posted. It's not generating vectors of dimension 9